# Prove that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i$ is a subspace of $\prod_{i \in I} U_i.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field, $I$ a nonempty set, and for each $i \in I$, $U_i$ a vector space over $F.$ Prove that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i$ is a subspace of $\prod_{i \in I} U_i.$

We first show that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i$ is nonempty. We know that $0 \in \prod_{i \in I} U_i$ is just the map that takes elements $i \in I$ to $0.$ Since $\operatorname{spt}(0) = \emptyset$ (the zero function maps everything to $0),$ we have $0 \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i.$ Suppose $f,g \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i.$ Then $f,g \in \prod_{i \in I} U_i$ and $\left\vert{\operatorname{spt}(f)}\right\vert, \left\vert{\operatorname{spt}(g)}\right\vert < \infty.$ For $f,g \in \prod_{i \in I} U_i,$ we define the sum by $(f+g)(i) = f(i)+g(i).$ Since $f(i),g(i) \in U_i$ for every $i,$ and each $U_i$ is a vector space over $F,$ it follows that $f(i)+g(i) \in U_i$ for every $i,$ and so $f+g \in \prod_{i \in I} U_i.$ Take $x \in \operatorname{spt}(f+g).$ Then $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x) \ne 0.$ Since $f(x) + g(x) \ne 0,$ then either $f(x) \ne 0$ or $g(x) \ne 0,$ meaning that $x \in \operatorname{spt}(f) \cup \operatorname{spt}(g).$ Thus $\operatorname{spt}(f+g) \subset \operatorname{spt}(f) \cup \operatorname{spt}(g)$ demonstrating that $\left\vert{\operatorname{spt}(f+g)}\right\vert < \infty.$ Combining $\left\vert{\operatorname{spt}(f+g)}\right\vert < \infty$ with the fact that $f+g \in \prod_{i \in I} U_i,$ it follows that $f+g \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i.$ Now let $c \in F$ and $f \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i.$ Since every $U_i$ is a vector space closed under scalar multiplication and $f(i) \in \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i,$ one has $(cf)(i) = cf(i) \in \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i,$ so that $cf \in \prod_{i \in I} U_i.$ If $c = 0,$ then clearly $\operatorname{spt}(cf) = \operatorname{spt}(0) < \infty.$ Suppose that $c \ne 0$ and let $x \in \operatorname{spt}(cf).$ Then $cf(x) \ne 0,$ implying that $f(x) \ne 0,$ which means that $x \in \operatorname{spt}(f).$ Thus $\operatorname{spt}(cf) \subset \operatorname{spt}(f),$ proving that $\left\vert{\operatorname{spt}(cf)}\right\vert < \infty.$ Hence $cf \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i.  \Box$

Questions: Is my work correct so far? How do I prove that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i$ is closed under scalar multiplication? (answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work so far is good, except for the last sentence which I assume is a typo.

For scalar multiplication, note that either $c = 0$ or $\operatorname{spt}(cf) = \operatorname{spt}(f)$.